# Numpy argmax - random tie breaking

Tags: python, numpy

In [numpy.argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) function, tie breaking between multiple max elements is so that the first element is returned.
Is there a functionality for randomizing tie breaking so that all maximum numbers have equal chance of being selected?

Below is an example directly from numpy.argmax documentation.

```
>>> b = np.arange(6)
>>> b[1] = 5
>>> b
array([0, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> np.argmax(b) # Only the first occurrence is returned.
1
```

I am looking for ways so that 1st and 5th elements in the list are returned with equal probability.

Thank you!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use `np.random.choice` -

```
np.random.choice(np.flatnonzero(b == b.max()))
```

Let's verify for an array with three max candidates -

```
In [298]: b
Out[298]: array([0, 5, 2, 5, 4, 5])

In [299]: c=[np.random.choice(np.flatnonzero(b == b.max())) for i in range(100000)]

In [300]: np.bincount(c)
Out[300]: array([    0, 33180,     0, 33611,     0, 33209])
```

Comment: if you have floats instead of ints, you may want to replace `b == b.max()` with `np.isclose(b, b.max())`

Comment: `arr.max()` can be replaced by `np.max(arr)` for clarity that numpy array is involved

Comment: roughly three times slower!

Comment: For better performance you could try `max(enumerate(b), key=lambda key: (key[1], rng.random()))[0]`

Answer (score 16):

In the case of a multi-dimensional array, `choice` won't work.

An alternative is

```
def randargmax(b,**kw):
  """ a random tie-breaking argmax"""
  return np.argmax(np.random.random(b.shape) * (b==b.max()), **kw)
```

If for some reason generating random floats is slower than some other method, `random.random` can be replaced with that other method.

Comment: roughly 18 times slower!

Comment: `**kw` should also be passed to `max()` (e.g., `axis`), so it's correctly calculated (e.g., the max per row instead of the global max).

Comment: Also, there's a chance the random value is 0. I think doing a `+1` to the random value fixes this unlikely case.

Answer (score 9):

Easiest way is

```
np.random.choice(np.where(b == b.max())[0])
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation along with the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Since the accepted answer may not be obvious, here is how it works:

- `b == b.max()` will return an array of booleans, with values of `true` where items are max and values of `false` for other items
- `flatnonzero()` will do two things: ignore the `false` values (nonzero part) then return indices of `true` values. In other words, you get an array with indices of items matching the max value
- Finally, you pick a random index from the array

Answer (score 2):

Additional to @Manux's answer,

Changing `b.max()` to `np.amax(b,**kw, keepdims=True)` will let you do it along axes.

```
def randargmax(b,**kw):
    """ a random tie-breaking argmax"""
    return np.argmax(np.random.random(b.shape) * (b==b.max()), **kw)

randargmax(b,axis=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a comparison between the two main solutions by [@divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) and [@shyam-padia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4419522/shyam-padia) :

**method (1)** - using `np.where`

```
np.random.choice(np.where(b == b.max())[0])
```

**method (2)** - using `np.flatnonzero`

```
np.random.choice(np.flatnonzero(b == b.max())
```

### Code

Here is the code I wrote for the comparison:

> ```
> def method1(b, bmax,):
>     return np.random.choice(np.where(b == bmax)[0])
>
> def method2(b, bmax):
>     return np.random.choice(np.flatnonzero(b == bmax))
>
> def time_it(n):
>     b = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.4, 0.1, 5.0, 0.3, 0.1])
>     bmax = b.max()
>
>     start = time.perf_counter()
>     for i in range(n):
>         method1(b, bmax)
>     elapsed1 = time.perf_counter() - start
>     start = time.perf_counter() 
>     for i in range(n):
>         method2(b, bmax)
>     elapsed2 = time.perf_counter() - start
>
>     print(f'method1 time: {elapsed1} - method2 time: {elapsed2}')
>     return elapsed1, elapsed2
> ```

### Results

The following figure shows the computation time for running each method for `[100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]` iterations where x-axis represents number of iterations, y-axis shows time in seconds. It can be seen that `np.where` performs better than `np.flatnonzero` when number of iterations increases. Note that the x-axis has a logarithmic scale.

[image]

To show how the two methods compare in the lower iteration, we can re-plot the previous results by making the y-axis being a logarithmic scale. We can see that `np.where` stays always better than `np.flatnonzero`.

[image]